# Ionic - Manipulating http responce data before displaying

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, httpresponse

How can i take a value from http response and format or manipulate it before using it in the html page.

My code so far:

**.ts file**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public getAftaler: GetaftalerProvider) {

this.getAftaler.hentAftaler().subscribe(data =>{
  this.aftaleData = data;
   console.log(data);

  })

 }
```

Here i got the array back - it's ok

I can display the data in the html file also

**.html file**

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let records of aftaleData" >
    <ion-card-header [innerHtml]=records.full_name>

    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>

    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

My problem is the that the item 'records.start_date' is a full date and i only want to display the time 'H:mm'

How and where can i do that ?

Can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: @Eakethet - I've tried the pipe way
My html looks like this
     <ion-col>{{records.start_date}}</ion-col>
     this outputs 2018-04-24 08:15:00
Trying pipe (with any format)
     <ion-col>{{records.start_date | date:'HH:mm'}}</ion-col>
I got this error:
InvalidPipeArgument: '2018-04-24 09:30:00' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: Well you can loop through your data, and for each record set start_date as new Date(record.start_date) when you are loading those datas.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it in getAftaler service or inside the subscription.

For the second case, you can simply do it as the following:

```
this.getAftaler.hentAftaler().subscribe(data =>{
    /*Do it here inside Subscription*/
    this.aftaleData = data;
    /*maybe loop over aftaleData here and change what you want*/
    console.log(data);
})
```

To easily format a date, you do this through pipes - an easy, simple and very helpful concept.

[Here you can find the official angular documentation of date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)